# How do I kill a specific process running in the background from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, kill

Assuming this is a Windows 7 machine - and we're talking about batch scripts on the Windows command line.

Imagine I want to start and stop two different processes running in the background, and run things whilst they running in the background. For example:

```
START /B CMD /C tomcatA.bat
doSomeStuff
stopTomcatACmd
START /B CMD /C tomcatB.bat
doSomeStuff
stopTomcatBCmd
```

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the `stopTomcatBCmd`.  On a Linux machine you could just `kill` the `pid`.

My question is: **How do I kill a specific process running in the background in Windows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **taskkill** is what you're looking for.
With it you can kill a running process by its ID or image name (name of the .exe file).

You can read a detailed usage explanation on this page:
http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm

Answer (score 2):

TaskKill should do the job. you can write in the exact name of the task to kill, i.e. to kill all firefox processes

```
C:\>Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F
```

or you can check the PID of specific task by writing Tasklist, and then kill the task by mentioning its PID i.e.

```
C:\>Taskkill /PID 26356 /F
```

Comment: Is there a way for each script to do that?

Comment: Which script are you talking about?

Comment: Please see the question, there are two different processes and two different scripts. Each script needs to kill its own process only despite having the same app name.

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this you can almost always find a utility you can use as part of the Sysinternals suite. In this case I would recommend PsKill: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pskill

```
Usage: pskill [-t] [\\computer [-u username [-p password]]] <process ID | name>
```

example: `pskill notepad`

Mark's article discussing usage of PsList and PsKill: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/pslist-and-pskill

Comment: not sure what prompted the downvote but I've added an example showing how to use this tool